# Rust: defining trait for generic function that compares length

Tags: generics, rust

So I want to write a function like this:

```
fn is_longer_than<T>(thing: T, threshold: int) -> bool {
    thing.len() > threshold 
}
```

I'm pretty new to rust and static typing / generics in general, but from what I understand you need to constrain `T` with a trait that, in this case, implements the method `len`

I tried to do something like this:

```
trait HasLength {
    fn len(&self) -> int
}

fn is_longer_than<T>(thing: HasLength, threshold: int) -> bool {
    thing.len() > threshold 
}
```

But that doesn't work. What am I missing? I'm guessing there is a pre-defined trait that covers this case? Even so, is there a way to define it anyways (for the sake of learning)

Answer (score 4):

You do need to constrain `T` to the trait `HasLength`, this is done with the syntax like `<T: HasLength>`.

```
trait HasLength {
    fn len(&self) -> int;
}

fn is_longer_than<T: HasLength>(thing: T, threshold: int) -> bool {
    thing.len() > threshold 
}
```

This declares that the function `is_longer_than` takes any type `T` that has an implementation of `HasLength`. Note that you will have to define an implementation (with `impl`) for every type you may want to pass to `is_longer_than`.

Alternatively, the function could be defined as:

```
fn is_longer_than2(thing: &HasLength, threshold: int) -> bool {
    thing.len() > threshold 
}
```

This declares a function that takes a *trait object*, which will include both a reference to the data and one to a dynamic dispatch table for the trait. You will still have to define the appropriate `impl` in order to create the trait object.

The difference between the two forms is that the first form will be specialized for every type, that is, a different version of the function will be compiled for every type that is used with the function. The second form will be more like OO-code in language like Java - only a single version of the function will be compiled, but this version will have to use the dynamic dispatch table to call `len`.

Here is an example `impl` for the HasLength trait, that defines the length of an `i32` as the number of base-10 digits needed to represent it:

```
impl HasLength for i32 {
  fn len(&self) -> int { self.to_string().len() as int }
}
```

Comment: can you explain the definition of `impl` in this case? I've been going through the guide and I see how `impl` works with manually and arbitrarily defined methods, but I don't understand how to connect it with len() which is already defined by the standard library.

Comment: @AllTheTime creating a trait based on methods that already exist is probably a different question. I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: @AllTheTime It sounds like you want structural typing (aka duck typing) -  a way to refer to all types that define a method `len`. This is not possible in Rust. However, see my new edit with an example `impl`.

Comment: @AllTheTime: You can implement the trait manually to call the inherent method: http://is.gd/Qd5eVt

Comment: @Shepmaster: It's possible, thanks to unified function call syntax (UFCS): http://is.gd/Qd5eVt

Comment: @FrancisGagné but can you do something like in Go, where you define an interface and then magically all types that match the interface *implement* the interface. In your example, you'd have to have `impl<T> HasLength for Vec<T>` and `impl<T> HasLength for String` and so on, for every type that has `len()`, correct? That's how I read this question.

Comment: @Shepmaster: No, that's called structural typing/duck typing, and Rust doesn't have that. I thought your "I'm not sure it's possible" meant you thought you wouldn't be able to call an inherent method (a method defined in an impl that's not for a trait) from a trait method's body, which I think was true until UFCS was implemented.